# take a value from a previous row

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql table like this

[image]

This is the table of a case in a psychiatry it contains a pid which is the id of the patient an the fid of the case because a patient can have more then one case.
Now i have a table with all cases and i have to generate the exit of a patient.

For Example the patient Max Müller with the PID 123456 an 3 cases.
As the exit for the first case i need to take the entry from the second case is there a possibily do it with a case statement like this

```
where numberOfCases > 1 then entry where numberOfCase +  else 'NULL' end as exit
```

at the end i want to have a table like this[image]

For exampe this Patient with 3 cases (name of the patient is blacked) i woult like to have a new column Exit and the Exit is the Entry of the next case( entry is the last column)

[image]

Comment: could u please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: i have added a output table and a sample patient

Comment: I did not understand the question completely, because in the title you write about value from previous row and in the question text you say it is about the next case. However, the solution you are looking for is either LAG() or LEAD() window functions, where you PARTITION BY PID and ORDER BY FID.
P.S. You really should provide input data and desired output according to the stackoverflow rules.

Comment: It helps the community a lot if you post the statements to create the table and the statements to insert the data. If you choose to use screenshots then whoever wants to help you needs to start writing the solution from scratch. You're less likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` analytical function.

```
SELECT T.*,
       LEAD(ENTRY) OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY ENTRY) AS EXIT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Cheers!!